# Basic JavaScript Function Issue

Tags: javascript, function

Ok, so I am trying to call the convert function in the calculate_drug function but the final "sotp" "start" alert keeps coming up as undefined.  I am assuming this is because it thinks convert is not defined.  This is a python code I'm trying to convert to JS and I'm obviously not very familiar with JS.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the button</p>
<button onclick="calculate_drug()">Drug</button>


<script>

function convert(time)
{
minutes = time.substr(-2)
hours = Math.floor(time/100)
con_time = (hours * 60) + parseInt(minutes)
}

function calculate_drug(start, stop)
{
start = prompt("Enter Start Time")
stop = prompt("Enter Stop Time")
start = convert(start)
alert(start)
stop = convert(stop)
alert(stop)
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be declaring variables with `var`

Comment: @Geo Doesn't need to, though; there are parameters that are promptly read in via a `prompt`. It's weird, but there it is.

Comment: @DaveNewton True. I didn't read the whole thing before replying. I posted an answer to the question that is actually working though :)

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `return`, so the result is always `undefined`.

And note variables without `var` declaration are treated as global variables, which is highly not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from the convert function.

```
function convert(time)
{
    minutes = time.substr(-2)
    hours = Math.floor(time/100)
    con_time = (hours * 60) + parseInt(minutes)
    return con_time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not js expert but almost all my java scripts look like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("js kicked");
    $("#req").addClass("active open");
    $("#req-history").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Sir, this is jQuery, and the thing he is using is plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return a value

```
function convert(time)
{
    minutes = time.substr(-2)
    hours = Math.floor(time/100)
    con_time = (hours * 60) + parseInt(minutes)

    return con_time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 function convert(time)
        {
            var minutes = time.substr(-2);
            var hours = Math.floor(minutes/100);
            var con_time = (hours * 60) + parseInt(minutes);

            return con_time;
        }

        function calculate_drug()
        {

            var startTime = prompt("Enter Start Time");

             var stopTime = prompt("Enter Stop Time");
            startTime = convert(startTime);
             alert(startTime);
            stopTime = convert(stopTime);
             alert(stopTime);
        }
```